# How to achieve layout with 2 columns of equal height with 1 element in first column, 2 in second, without floats?

Tags: html, css, layout, stylesheet

I am trying to make a header for a site that has a logo in the left column, and a rotating image banner and the top-level navigation on the right, without using floats. What am I doing wrong here?

This is what I would like it to look like:

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo"><p>Logo</p></div>
    <div id="right">    
        <div id="rotator"><p>Rotator</p></div>
        <div id="navigation"><p>Navigation</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#header{
    width: 1024px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: yellow;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 0px;
}
#logo{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    width: 306px;
    height: 192px;
    font-size: 0px;
}
#right{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: black;
    width: 718px;
    height: 192px;
    font-size: 0px;
}
#rotator{
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
    width: 718px;
    height: 132px;
}
#navigation{
    display: block;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 718px;
    height: 60px;
}
p{
    font-size: 24px;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This is what it ends up looking like:
[image]

Comment: Why don't you want to use floats?

Comment: Partially as an exercise to see if it could be done, and also because I don't really like floats. In my opinion, they are messy, and it can be frustrating to have an element on your page that has "no" height. By eliminating floats I can eliminate the need for a clearfix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting `vertical-align: top;` on the logo and right divs

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcurran/UqMPz/)

```
#logo{
display: inline-block;
background-color: red;
width: 306px;
height: 192px;
font-size: 0px;
vertical-align: top;
```

}

```
#right{
display: inline-block;
background-color: black;
width: 718px;
height: 192px;
font-size: 0px;
vertical-align: top;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
#right {

background-color: black;
font-size: 0;
height: 192px;
position: absolute;
right: 168px;
top: 28px;
width: 718px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using display:table & table-cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/zR9GZ/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col1">LOGO</div>
    <div class="col2">
        <div class="rotator">ROTATOR</div>
        <div class="navigation">NAVIGATION</div>
    </div>
</div>

.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    color:# fff;
}

.col1, .col2 {
    display: table-cell;
}

.col1 {
    background: red;
    width: 25%;
}

.col2 {
    width: 75%;
}

.rotator {
    background: green;
}

.navigation {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: And?  inline-block has quirky support in IE7, but I see it used here without the usual suspects to get it working.  Less than 2% of the browsers in use are IE7.  For my work, I don't count it in my list of browsers to support.

Comment: @user1721135 - You're correct, but the OP never specified support for IE7 (or indeed any particular browser) an as cimmanon says, IE7 isn't that widely used these days.

Comment: well ie7 support is a given, especially since its pretty easy supporting it. ofc its only easy if actually know a little bit about html/css.

Comment: what are you saying. 1.1% get a broken layout or what. might go unnoticed by the client, but sure is bad practice.

Comment: Then it's bad practice ftw :-)

Answer (score -1):

Though flexbox isn't quite ready for production designs, here's what a responsive solution would look like (try resizing it!):

```
#header {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#header{
    background-color: yellow;
    font-size: 0px;
}

#logo{
    background-color: red;
    width: 306px;
    height: 192px;
    font-size: 0px;
}
#right{
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 0px;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    min-width: 40%;
}
#rotator{
    background-color: green;
    flex: 2 1 auto;
}
#navigation{
    background-color: blue;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2UjC3/ (prefixes not included)

Until enough browsers support flexbox, my recommendation is to use the display table/table-cell solution by Billy Moat.